# Notation for the set of zero divisors in a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, notation, terminology

If $R$ is a nonzero ring with identity then I have seen the *group of units* denoted by $R^{\times}$ or possibly $R^*$ in some texts. In a *classical ring* there is a trichotomy which declares each element in $R$ is either zero, a unit, or a zero-divisor. Naturally, for a classical ring, the set of zero-divisors and $\{0\}$ is the complement of $R$ by the group of units; $\text{set of zero divisors in $R$} \cup \{0 \} = R - R^{ \times}$.

My question is simply this:

> Is there a **common notation** for the set of zero-divisors in a ring ?

Thanks in advance for your insight.

Comment: What are some nontrivial examples of classical rings? It seems weird that $\mathbb Z$ and $k[x]$ are not classical.

Comment: @Hoot one sided artinian rings (or even rings satisfying DCC on chains of right ideals generated by the powers of an element), Von Neumann regular rings.

Comment: For example, any linear associative algebra forms a classical ring.

Comment: (my algebra is over the real numbers in the comment above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one I see the most is like $Z(R)$, sometimes writing $Z^*(R)$ for the ones that aren't zero.

This collides with some other usages though, notably the center of the ring and the singular ideal of a ring.

I think I've seen it as $ZD(R)$ too, somewhere.

Comment: Atiyah & MacDonald use $D$ for the set of zero divisors. This is also not the best notation since it could be confused with *divisors*.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. I was pondering the use of $Z$, or $Z(R)$, but I also dislike it for the same reasons. At the moment, I think I'm going to use $\mathbf{zd}(R)$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a common notation for the set of zero divisors as the union of (radicals of) annihilators, i.e., 
$$"Ann_D(R)"=\text{the set of zero divisors }=\bigcup_{0\ne x\in R} \sqrt{\text{Ann}(x)}=\bigcup_{0\ne x\in R}\text{Ann}(x).$$

Edit: Still there remains the question for a short notation of the set of zero divisors.

Comment: Maybe a dumb question: why do you need to take radicals?

Comment: It is not a dump question - see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/371929/the-set-of-zero-divisors-is-the-union-of-radicals-of-annihilators).

Comment: I have to admit that I've never seen this "notation".

Comment: @user26857 It is related to annihilators, which is not an uncommon notation. Or did you mean the first notation ? There you are right.

Comment: Yes, I mean $Ann_D(R)$. Writing the set of zero-divisors like the union of annihilators is not a notation, I suppose.

Comment: OK, I will edit this.

Comment: So... Where does this appear? I have not seen it...  Comparing it with other conventional uses of Ann, the notation suggests rather that things in the set annihilate all of R